# How to login to a website from another system through ssh

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, login

I'm new at this system.

In my University to access the internet, we need to login to the server using our LDAP id. As in the link:

[image]

We will automatically get signed out after a particular time. I set up a workstation in Linux(Ubuntu 14.04), due to some specific reasons it doesn't have access to monitor. So I'm using it through ssh.

Now my question is, how can I login from my laptop(macOS Sierra) using ssh. Means I want to go that page and need to give username and password so that I can download my python required packages and libraries.

Edit 1: Laptop and the Ubuntu workstation are in the same network.
Edit 2: I know the ip address of my workstation.
Edit 3: I want to install some python packages, but without login, I can't do that

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Is your laptop and the Ubuntu workstation in the same network? Do you know the IP address of the Ubuntu workstation? What happens when you try to ssh from the laptop? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/972594/edit) your question and provide the exact error messages.

Comment: There are Shell Webbrowser Like e.g. `w3m`. To install it on your Ubuntu use `sudo apt install w3m`. Than you can browse  the Internet within the shell  e.g. `w3m https://www.google.de` but I'm not sure if this would work in your case because it seems to me you are speaking about opening a websession on the University page before being able to browse and I'm not sure if this is supported by e.g. `w3m`

Comment: @derHugo that should work. I've logged into captive portals with lynx and w3m

Answer (score 2):

The login form on that site probably does an HTTP POST request to login to the server. You can replicate that with `wget` on the Ubuntu system, for example:

```
username='myusername'
password='mypassword'
wget --no-proxy --quiet --post-data="user=$username&pass=$password&submit=submit" https://internet.foo.bar
```

What you need to figure out, and we can't help with, is what the names of the form fields are (here I have used `user`, `pass` and `submit`). You'll have to inspect the source of the HTML page in Firefox or Chrome and see what the `id` values for the username and password fields are, and probably for the submit button too, and change the `wget` command's POST data accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Shell Webbrowser Like `w3m` to browse the page from within the Linux shell via ssh.

To install it run

```
 sudo apt install w3m
```

on the Linux machine.

Then browse the web using

```
 w3m https://www.google.de
```

or the page of your University. Than you should be able to provide your credentials and browse as in a Webbrowser.

To exit w3m press `q` and answer with `y`.

For a complete documentation look [here](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/MANUAL)

Comment: It would be better to use a non-HTTPS page. Browsers tend to error out when an HTTPS-only site like Google is intercepted by a captive portal. Google has a standard page for this purpose, used on Android, etc.: http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204

Comment: Used this as example since the OP's University page also seems to be HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

You can ssh from your laptop into the workstation using X forwarding and use the browser to log into your university account.

First, enable X forwarding in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the workstation by specifying `X11Forwarding yes` and then `ssh -X you@workstation` from your laptop and run the browser on the workstation from command line, the browser window should appear on your laptop screen.